# Как это исправить?

Tags: android

Смущает, что текст дублируется криво. Пробовал переустановить Android Studio, не помогло. А если изменять версию в build.grandle, то возникают другие ошибки с AndroidManifest.xml.

Вот сам текст ошибки:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageDebug' (type 'PackageApplication').

> File'C:\Users\huawei\Desktop\1.8.7_simpledraw\app\D:Users\huawei\Desktop.android\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.signingConfigData.storeFile' does not exist.

Comment: Firstly translate your question please - Для начала переведите ваш вопрос пожалуйста.

Comment: Так же приложите текст ошибки текстом

Comment: Меня смутило, что там путь криво дублируется

Comment: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageDebug' (type 'PackageApplication').
> File 'C:\Users\huawei\Desktop\1.8.7_simpledraw\app\D:Users\huawei\Desktop\.android\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.signingConfigData.storeFile' does not exist.
вот ошибка

Comment: всю информацию внесите в вопрос и переведите его, иначе его закроют и вам никто не сможет помочь

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

У вас не находит ключ для подписи приложения. Делаем так:

```
Build -> Generate Signed APK. Create your key (or choose existing) -> next -> next -> done
```

дальше в build.gradle проверяем наличие этого ключа:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("/yourkey.jks") //<------------------------
            storePassword "YourPassword"
            keyAlias "YourAlias"
            keyPassword "YourPassword"
        }
    }
```

Вот есть подобные проблемы и их обсуждения: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211444/android-specified-for-property-signingconfig-storefile-does-not-exist), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629723/signingconfig-storefile-does-not-exist-when-i-try-to-run-the-project), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202942/how-fix-file-xxx-specified-for-property-signingconfig-storefile-does-not-exi).